# Guassian is not defined

Tags: python, curve-fitting, lmfit

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from lmfit import Model
x=np.array([4698.031, 4698.027, 4698.024, 4698.021, 4698.017, 
4698.014,4698.011, 4698.007, 4698.004, 4698.001, 4697.997, 4697.994, 
4697.991, 4697.987, 4697.984, 4697.981, 4697.977, 4697.974, 4697.971, 
4697.967, 4697.964, 4697.961, 4697.957, 4697.954, 4697.951, 4697.947, 
4697.944, 4697.941, 4697.937, 4697.934, 4697.931, 4697.927, 4697.924, 
4697.921, 4697.917])
y=np.array([0.56565, 0.586575, 0.70335, 0.991245, 1.447545, 4.944375, 
11.97281, 18.22095, 19.7613, 17.13792, 13.35083, 10.26506, 7.898505, 
5.084775, 2.4192, 1.34358, 0.829905, 1.31322, 3.2049, 4.0095, 2.83263, 
1.51605, 0.643275, 0.48972, 0.432675, 0.084375, 0.135345, 0.362145, 
0.34425, 0.307125, 0.469125, 0.297, 0.183255, 0.528855, 0.523125])
gmodel = Model(gaussian, prefix='p1_') + Model(gaussian, prefix='p2_')
params = gmodel.make_params(p1_amp=0.1, p1_cen=4697.97, p1_wid=0.005, 
p2_amp=0.5, p2_cen=4698.00, p2_wid=0.005)


params['p1_cen'].min = x.min()
params['p1_cen'].max = 4697.98
params['p2_cen'].min = 4697.98
params['p2_cen'].max = x.max()

result = gmodel.fit(y, params, x=x)
```

**I'm runing this program and the Message Error says:**

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "", line 8, in 
>       gmodel = lt.Model(gaussian, prefix='p1_') + lt.Model(gaussian, prefix='p2_') NameError: name 'gaussian' is not defined..

Comment: You need to define `gaussian` function. you don't define it anywhere. see here :https://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/model.html

Comment: Yes that can be used as a model not as a function see Jacques answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define the `gaussian` function:

```
from numpy import exp

def gaussian(x, amp, cen, wid):
    return amp * exp(-(x-cen)**2 / wid)
```

or use the built-in `GaussianModel`:

```
from lmfit.models import GaussianModel

gmodel = GaussianModel(prefix='p1_') + GaussianModel(prefix='p2_')
```

Answer (score 2):

gaussian is a function you have to define so you can use it in Model.
This is well explained in this [docs](https://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/model.html#motivation-and-simple-example-fit-data-to-gaussian-profile).

You have to add this to your code:

```
def gaussian(x, amp, cen, wid):
     return amp * exp(-(x-cen)**2 / wid)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to define gaussian:

```
import numpy as np
def gaussian(x, amp, cen, wid):
  return amp * np.exp(-(x-cen)**2 / wid)
```

See the model class section on this page: https://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/model.html#lmfit.model.Model